selenium python to create auto_login
I have element in loginpage like this
<input ng-model="$ctrl.username" id="loginUserName" class="form-control ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" sw-autofocus="" style="">

tried to store in el by
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loginUserName"]')

got error message
NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=130.0.6723.92)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF68EF43AF5+28005]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EEA83F0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68ED4580A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68ED1FA85]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EDC2AD7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EDDB1B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EDBB7E3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68ED875C8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68ED88731]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF68F23646D+3118813]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF68F286CC0+3448624]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF68F27CF3D+3408301]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF68F00A44B+841403]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EEB344F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EEAF4C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EEAF65D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68EE9EBB9]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC1173257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC12BCAF08+40]

what's wrong with the method or code?

Ensure the browser window is open

I have answered below but it would be helpful to include more context or surrounding code from the script. The error is very general relating to the browser not being accessible which could be caused by a number of things. I will edit the answer if something changes from added context.

Based on the NoSuchWindowException error it is likely that your Selenium instance has lost connection with the browser window due to a reason that it unclear.
Try these:

Ensure the window is acitve
Restart any driver sessions.
Switch to the correct window/tab.
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])



I have also seen this issue previously where the cookies invalidate the session after several requests so you may try deleting them prior.
driver.delete_all_cookies()

